# Verify :$\cos^2x=\cot^2x-\frac{\cos^2x}{\tan^2x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\cos^2x=\cot^2x-\frac{\cos^2x}{\tan^2x}$$

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos^2x=\frac{\sin^2x}{\tan^2x}\\
\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x\\
\frac{\sin^2x}{\tan^2x}=\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\tan^2x}\\
\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\tan^2x}=\frac{1}{\tan^2x}-\frac{\cos^2x}{\tan^2x}\\
\cos^2x=\cot^2x-\frac{\cos^2x}{\tan^2x}$$

Comment: Words, please! :-)

Comment: Sure!${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What do you mean Sure! ?

Comment: It's my duty to edit posts to make them readable and more professional.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cot^2x-\frac{\cos^2x}{\tan^2x}=\frac{1}{tan^2x}-\frac{\cos^2x}{\tan^2x}=\frac{sin^2x}{tan^2x}=cos^2x
$$